# Get CreatedBy using REST API SharePoint

Tags: rest, api

How can I get `CreatedBy` field using REST API SharePoint? Below is the code

```
var Ownurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Listname')/items?$select=Author,ID&$filter=ID eq 1;  

        $.ajax({  
               url: Ownurl,  
               headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },  
               async:false,  
               success: function (data) {  
                        var items = data.d.results;  
                        if (items[0].Author!= "") {  
                                author = items[0].Author;
                            }  
                        },eror: function (data) {  
                            alert("An error occurred. Please try again.");  
                            }  
               });
```

But somehow I am not able to get `Author`.
Is there anything wrong?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks.

Comment: CreatedBy is type of person & group. So i think you have to make changes in query. Refer this [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31210.sharepoint-2013-get-user-details-from-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try following REST URL, you must expand the Person and Group field.

```
var Ownurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Listname')/items?$filter=Id eq 1&$expand=Author&$select=Author/Id"
```

Comment: You can try like this to get the ID of the Authour without expanding the field 
`var Ownurl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Listname')/items?$select=AuthorId"`

Comment: @VishnuPS I get `Column 'AuthorId' does not exist` doing that.

Comment: @VishnuPS Could you please share your REST API Url..

Comment: @VishnuPS Actually, I figured out my issue.  I could not include a filter like I wanted to do.  That line was fine. It just meant I would have to check for the length of my results and iterate each one, then check if the `data.d.results[i].AuthorId == authorId;`  ...

Comment: @RohitWaghela That actually IS the entire API URL... And I couldn't get your version to work, but his was fine...

Comment: @VishnuPS Great..